# htaccess wordpress custom redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've a Wordpress site, I want to make a custom redirect like this :

> All urls that doesn't start by /fr/ or /en/ or /es/ have to be redirect to /fr/

I've try this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr(.*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en(.*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es(.*)
RewriteRule . /fr/? [R=301,L]
```

Placed just after this :

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

It seems to work, but my problem is all images, css, js are impacted by this redirect, and aren't loaded.

Is there a solution de make this redirect only on URLs, no on assets ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule in .htaccess for redirects to make proper.

```
RewriteRule ^fr/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you precise more this rule ? I'm not sure that it respond to the problematic : All urls that doesn't start by /fr/ or /en/ or /es/ have to be redirect to /fr/.